# What is the HWND parameter in the Windows Procedure Functions?

Tags: winapi, msdn

I was testing some Win32 apps with c++, and in this code:

> LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
>
> _In_  HWND hwnd,
>
> _In_  UINT uMsg,
>
> _In_  WPARAM wParam,
>
> _In_  LPARAM lParam
>
> );

Looking at this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I couldn't really understand what the HWND is?

It says: `A handle to the window.`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is there behind the "Conceptual" section link on the MSDN page you refer to.

[About Windows - Window Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#window_handle):

> Window Handle
>
> After creating a window, the creation function returns a window handle
>   that uniquely identifies the window. A window handle has the HWND data
>   type; an application must use this type when declaring a variable that
>   holds a window handle. An application uses this handle in other
>   functions to direct their actions to the window.

[About Window Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Structure of a Window Procedure
>
> A window procedure is a function that has four parameters and returns
>   a signed value. The parameters consist of a window handle, a UINT
>   message identifier, and two message parameters declared with the
>   WPARAM and LPARAM data types. For more information, see WindowProc.

Comment: Looks fair enough, so it was just I who didn't know how to navigate in MSDN Documentation, thanks for the answer !.